# Is there a way to get statistical data about what the GC is collecting?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm trying to parse a certain data file.  The file is around 3 MB, and I expect the data structure it expands into to take up around 40 MB in memory.  I've verified this with a parser that produces correct results but is *extremely* slow.  I'm trying it with a different, much faster parser, but somehow when I run the parser it ends up consuming over 1.5 GB and blowing the 32-bit address space, and I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

The parser was produced by a parser generator that's obviously doing something very wrong.  I have the source code to the parser generator, but I don't know where to start looking to fix it.

What would really help would be if I knew where all that memory was coming from.  If I could parse a smaller file that would generate a few hundred MB of garbage, then run the GC and get back a report saying something like "collected 1 million instances of class X, 3 million instances of class Y, etc" then I would have a good idea as to what to focus on.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use memory profiler to troubleshoot these kinds of problems. It will show you what specific classes occupy the most memory and where they were created.

Some editions of Visual Studio have a built-in profiler. Also there are several  commercial ones, for example Redgate ANTS Memory Profiler or dotMemory from Jetbrains. They have trial versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotMemory](http://jetbrains.com/dotmemory) from JetBrains. If you run your program from profiler you can collect information about stacks where objects were created. And when you take shapshot It will help you to find out what methods eats most of the memory.
And than you can investigate it with help of simple tree or icicle chart, it looks like that:

[image]